# Copy iterm2 from remote server using it2copy

Tags: macos, iterm2

I installed `it2copy` from Shell Integration, and it works fine on local:

```
$ it2copy x.db
```

However, as soon as I ssh into another (linux) machine, it doesn't work:

```
$ it2copy
it2copy: command not found
```

Am I missing something here? I thought the terminal would automatically recognize that command on any remote server and copy the data to the clipboard:

> **it2copy**
> Copies text to the pasteboard. Works over ssh. Accepts either standard input or a named file.

Source: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-utilities.html. Is there something I need to install remotely as well to get this working? I also tried doing:

```
$ curl -L https://iterm2.com/shell_integration/install_shell_integration.sh | bash
```

On the remote server and that didn't seem to do anything. How can I get copy-paste (or any shell integration utils) to work via iTerm2 on a remote server?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install that specific script onto the machine, in the case of `it2copy`, the following will work:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2-shell-integration/main/utilities/it2copy
$ chmod 755 it2copy
$ mv it2copy /usr/bin/
```

Now you can use the command to copy anything over.